# Dependent Contact - Add (user with the specified email already exists)

Tags: b1-b2-visas, b2visa

I am trying to add my mother as a dependent in my father's profile. I canceled an old application and started a new one. While entering the email id of the dependent, I am getting this error message: "A user with the specified email already exists. Please choose a unique email."

Any idea how to get around this issue?

Comment: Choose a unique email, perhaps?

Comment: The funny thing is this email id hadn't been used earlier. All I did was cancel an opened application and start a new one. If I use a different email ID now, it will not match the email ID provided in DS-160. I am very confused at this point!

Comment: stuck in a similar problem. Any solution?